# Solidity Returning Array of Struct Error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging, solidity-0.8.x

I want to return an array of structs because i want to output all my data.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract
{
    mapping(uint256 => People) dataList;
    uint256[] countArr;
    struct People{
        string name;
        uint256 favNum;
    }
```

In this function, i set the data of my struct object and then include it in my mapping.

```
    function setPerson(string memory _name,uint256 _id, uint256 _favNum) public {
        dataList[_id]= People(_name,_favNum);
        countArr.push(_id);
    }
```

This function here gets me the data of my specified struct object.

```
    function getPerson(uint _id) public view returns(string memory,uint256){
        return (dataList[_id].name, dataList[_id].favNum);
    }
```

Now here is the function i think that is causing me trouble because in this function i want to return not the data of a single People object but all of my data and whenever i run this function on my REMIX IDE console it shows me the error: call to MyContract.getAllData errored: VM error: revert.  revert
**The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.**

```
    function getAllData()public view returns(People[] memory){
        uint256 count = (countArr.length);
        uint256 i = 0;
        People[] memory outputL= new People[](count);
        while(count >= 0){
            (string memory nam,uint256 num) = getPerson(count-1);
            People memory temp = People(nam,num);
            outputL[i]=temp;
            count--;
            i++;
        }
        return outputL;
    }                
}
```

Can anyone help and explain what is wrong and how can i get it running?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the logic in `while()` condition and array length. In your original smart contract, you can use `count` variable for track the array length minus 1 but this last operation is wrong. Because the length about array don't start from 0. Example:
If I have this array:

[0] = element

[1] = element

[2] = element

***array_length is 3***

Because of this issue, if in people array there are 3 elements, count variable has value: 2 and when you initialize the outputL array, the dynamic length about this last object is 2 and this is wrong!
For this reason, you receive that error.

I adjusted your smart contract, and you can see it in the following lines:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract
{
    mapping(uint256 => People) dataList;
    uint256[] countArr;
    
    struct People{
        string name;
        uint256 favNum;
    }

    function setPerson(string memory _name,uint256 _id, uint256 _favNum) public {
        dataList[_id]= People(_name,_favNum);
        countArr.push(_id);
    }

    function getPerson(uint _id) public view returns(string memory,uint256){
        return (dataList[_id].name, dataList[_id].favNum);
    }

    function getAllData()public view returns(People[] memory){
        uint256 count = countArr.length;
        uint256 i = 0;
        People[] memory outputL = new People[](count);
        while(count > 0){
            (string memory nam,uint256 num) = getPerson(i);
            People memory temp = People(nam,num);
            outputL[i]=temp;
            count--;
            i++;
        }
        return outputL;
    }                
}
```

Comment: Yes so sorry i saw that after posting but unfortunately this still gives me the same error anything else you might suggest really appreciate your help

Comment: hey sorry for previous comment your solution worked,Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The change mentioned by @Kerry99 is correct. I tested it and can confirm that. Seems you have not deployed the contract with the change.

Comment: yeah i was messing up the while loop condition.